# Django 1.6 is the official documention wrong about aggregate on GenericRelation?

Tags: django

EDIT: It turns out **I am wrong**. Because some of the values are correct while some are wrong despite of no errors raised up. So **don't use aggregation API on a GenericRelation**.

The test code shown in my answer.

RAW:
[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-and-aggregation) says "Django’s database aggregation API doesn’t work with a GenericRelation.". But what I find is totally work, even when more complicated aggregation query:

```
Question.objects.aggregate(Count('vote'))

#more complicated, works totally correct
Question.objects.annotate(votes=Sum('vote__value')).order_by('-votes')
```

[image]

The related models are:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)        
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()  
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0) #-1 0 or 1

class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()
    vote = generic.GenericRelation(Vote)
```

Comment: I just tested it - using aggregation on a generic relation doesn't raise an error, it just doesn't work (returns falsy values). Are you sure you're getting the result you're excepting to see through the aggregation?

Comment: @yuvi You are right. Yesterday I only check part of the results and happened to get all the correct ones. Now I check all the items and find the wrong values. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my test code. You can easily check it.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

User = get_user_model()

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)        
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()  
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0) #-1 0 or 1

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s:%s'%(self.user,self.value)

class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()
    vote = generic.GenericRelation(Vote)

#itest.py
import random
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Sum,Count
from generic.models import *

User = get_user_model()

def init():
    for i in range(5):
        User.objects.create_user('user%s'%i)
    users = User.objects.all()

    for i in range(5):
        Question.objects.create(
            user=random.choice(users),
            content='some text %s'%i,
            )
    questions = Question.objects.all()

    for question in questions:
        for user in users:
            Vote.objects.create(
                user=user,
                content_object=question,
                value=random.choice([-1,0,1]),
            )

def test():
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    aggregate_questions = Question.objects.annotate(votes=Sum('vote__value')).order_by('-votes')
    for i in range(5):
        all_votes = questions[i].vote.all()
        print('real vote_logs for question %s is %s'%(i,all_votes))
        raw_votes = sum([v.value for v in all_votes])
        agg_votes = aggregate_questions[i].votes
        print('safe votes:%s;aggregate votes:%s'%(raw_votes,agg_votes))
```

Test log:

```
>>> from itest import *
>>> init()
>>> test()
real vote_logs for question 0 is [<Vote: user0:0>, <Vote: user1:-1>, <Vote: user
2:1>, <Vote: user3:0>, <Vote: user4:-1>]
safe votes:-1;aggregate votes:2
real vote_logs for question 1 is [<Vote: user0:1>, <Vote: user1:0>, <Vote: user2
:-1>, <Vote: user3:-1>, <Vote: user4:-1>]
safe votes:-2;aggregate votes:1
real vote_logs for question 2 is [<Vote: user0:0>, <Vote: user1:0>, <Vote: user2
:0>, <Vote: user3:0>, <Vote: user4:0>]
safe votes:0;aggregate votes:0
real vote_logs for question 3 is [<Vote: user0:1>, <Vote: user1:1>, <Vote: user2
:-1>, <Vote: user3:0>, <Vote: user4:1>]
safe votes:2;aggregate votes:-1
real vote_logs for question 4 is [<Vote: user0:0>, <Vote: user1:0>, <Vote: user2
:0>, <Vote: user3:1>, <Vote: user4:0>]
safe votes:1;aggregate votes:-2
>>>
```